# When and in which order should I watch One Piece movies?

Tags: one-piece

I have *One Piece* movies, but I don't know in which order to watch, means after how many episodes should I watch each movie:

- One Piece: The Movie
- Clockwork Island Adventure
- Chopper's Kingdom on the Island of Strange Animals
- Dead End Adventure
- The Cursed Holy Sword
- Baron Omatsuri and the Secret Island
- The Giant Mechanical Soldier of Karakuri Castle
- Episode of Alabasta: The Desert Princess and the Pirates
- Episode of Chopper Plus: Bloom in Winter, Miracle Sakura
- One Piece Film: Strong World
- One Piece 3D: Straw Hat Chase
- One Piece Film: Heart of Gold
- One Piece Film: Z
- One Piece Film: Gold

and which movies are filler?

any answer will be helpful. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, none of the movies is considered canon.

They are all unrelated to the story that we can follow in the manga. Maybe one of the exceptions is *Strong World* because the main villain does exist in the manga storyline, but the event itself is not placed into it. So from a storywise perspective, you can watch them as/when you want, nothing major from the storyline will be spoiled for you.

The only things that can be "spoiled" are new character that join the crew later on or some mentioning of events that have already happened in the manga (the latest *Gold* movie is an example of that).

If you don't mind, you can watch them in any order you want, but because of joining character, maybe you should start in the order they were released.

Comment: Strong world was written by Eiichoro Oda. It's the most canon-like movie you'll ever get to see.

Comment: i know, i said it can be viewed as an exception, although it was never directly mentioned in the manga